# Decoding RF Signal

Tags: rf, signal-processing

I have a motorized curtain and I'm trying to understand its rf control signal in order to control it from my arduino.

I got the times, and checked the code is not static. I believe it has some kind of "sequencial counter" but I could not decode and understand the logic. In resume, I'm trying the get the operations the manufacturer do in order to obfuscate the payload.

The timings I got for the same key, pressed in sequence, are:

```
396,400,396,804,396,408,800,800,396,408,396,408,396,408,396,408,800,400,400,796,404,400,804,800,804,396,400,800,804,800,400,400,404,404,400,404,400,400,404,400,804,396,404,796,24508,408,368,404,368,404,368,404,368,400,376,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,376,396,372,400,372,404,372,392,380,396,376,396,376,400,376,392,376,396,376,400,3872,396,384,392,384,420,384,420,384,420,384,416,792,408,388,812,388,416,388,416,388,416,388,416,388,412,796,408,392,400,392,408,392,808,388,412,392,412,392,412,796,404,396,804,796,404,392,404,392,404,396,804,796,404,396,400,396,804,800,400,396,400,396,400,396,804,396,408,800,804,392,408,396,408,396,408,396,408,800,400,400,800,396,408,804,796,804,396,400,800,804,800,400,404,400,404,400,400,404,404,400,400,808,392,404,796,24516,404,368,404,368,404,368,404,368,400,372,404,368,404,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,396,376,400,376,396,376,396,376,400,372,400,372,396,376,396,376,400,376,396,372,404,3868,400,380,392,384,420,384,416,388,420,384,420,788,408,388,812,388,416,388,416,388,416,384,416,392,412,796,404,392,404,392,404,392,804,396,416,388,408,396,412,796,404,392,808,796,404,392,404,392,404,392,808,796,400,396,400,400,800,804,400,392,404,396,400,396,800,400,404,804,800,396,408,396,408,400,400,400,404,804,396,404,796,400,404,804,800,804,396,400,800,804,796,400,404,400,404,400,404,400,400,404,404,804,392,404,796,24512,412,364,404,368,408,364,404,368,404,368,404,368,404,372,404,368,404,368,404,368,400,372,404,368,400,372,400,376,396,376,396,376,400,372,396,376,396,376,400,372,400,376,396,376,400,3868,400,380,392,384,420,384,416,388,416,388,420,788,412,384,816,384,416,388,416,388,416,388,416,388,416,792,408,388,404,392,408,388,812,388,416,388,412,392,412,796,400,396,808,796,404,392,404,396,400,396,804,800,400,396,400,396,804,800,400,396,400,396,400,396,804,396,408,800,804,396,404,400,408,396,404,400,404,804,396,400,800,396,408,804,796,808,396,400,796,808,796,400,404,400,404,400,404,400,404,400,400,808,392,404,796

392,412,796,400,396,404,396,800,396,408,396,408,396,408,396,408,396,404,400,408,396,404,804,396,400,396,400,396,400,800,804,800,804,396,400,800,400,404,804,796,404,400,400,404,404,400,804,396,404,392,404,392,404,380,24124,404,368,408,368,404,372,400,368,404,368,400,372,404,368,404,368,404,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,376,396,372,400,376,396,376,396,376,396,376,396,376,396,376,400,3872,396,384,392,384,420,384,420,384,420,788,408,392,404,388,412,388,808,388,416,388,412,392,416,792,404,396,404,388,808,800,808,388,412,392,412,796,404,392,400,400,400,396,400,396,400,396,404,392,400,396,404,396,400,396,400,396,804,396,408,796,404,396,400,396,800,396,412,392,408,396,408,396,408,396,408,396,408,396,408,800,396,400,400,400,396,400,800,804,800,800,400,400,800,396,404,808,796,400,404,400,404,400,404,804,396,400,396,400,396,404,380,24124,408,368,404,368,404,368,404,368,404,368,404,368,400,372,400,372,404,368,404,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,396,376,400,372,400,372,396,380,392,376,400,376,396,376,396,376,396,376,400,3868,400,380,392,384,420,388,416,388,412,796,408,388,408,388,408,388,812,388,416,388,412,392,412,796,408,388,408,388,812,792,808,392,408,396,408,800,400,396,404,392,404,392,404,392,404,392,404,396,396,400,400,396,400,396,404,392,804,396,408,800,400,396,400,400,800,396,408,396,408,396,404,400,408,396,408,396,404,400,404,804,396,400,400,396,396,400,800,804,800,804,396,400,800,400,404,804,800,400,404,400,400,404,400,808,392,404,392,404,396,400,380,24124,404,368,412,364,404,368,404,368,404,368,404,368,404,368,404,372,400,368,404,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,372,400,376,396,376,396,376,400,372,396,376,400,372,400,3872,396,384,392,384,420,384,424,380,416,792,408,388,408,388,412,384,816,384,416,388,416,392,416,788,408,392,404,392,808,796,808,388,416,388,416,792,404,396,404,388,408,392,404,392,404,392,404,392,404,396,400,396,400,396,404,392,804,396,408,800,400,396,400,396,804,396,408,396,408,396,408,396,404,400,404,396,408,396,408,800,400,396,400
```

[This site helps visualize the timings](http://test.sui.li/oszi/)  (just copy and paste)

I believe it uses modulation ASK and Manchester Encoding (not sure about that), and the binary data I got is (the timings for third key press I did not save):

```
1010101010100101101010101010010101011010101001011001010101100101011001010101101001101010101001011010011001011001101010101010010110

1010101010010101011010101001010110011010100101010101010101010101101001010110101010101010100101010110011001011010011010101001010101

1010101010011010101010101001101001011010100110101001010101011010011001010110010101101010100110101010011001011010101010101001101010
```

[This link](https://pushstack.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/reversing-somfy-rts/) explain what I'm trying to do, but using a control from another manufacturer. The result, is better explained [here](https://pushstack.wordpress.com/somfy-rts-protocol/).

If is useful, I press the same key 2 times in other identical control and the timings I got are (I believe it changes the address and the 'counter'):

```
408,400,408,400,412,396,408,396,416,400,816,388,412,792,820,796,816,792,416,396,820,384,412,796,416,388,416,396,412,396,416,392,412,396,820,384,420,788,24636,404,376,400,376,396,384,396,376,400,380,396,384,396,380,396,380,396,380,396,384,392,384,396,380,392,388,392,384,388,388,392,388,392,384,392,384,392,384,392,388,388,388,384,392,392,3900,392,392,384,396,412,396,408,404,412,392,412,804,404,400,804,400,408,404,408,396,408,400,412,396,408,808,400,404,400,400,400,404,800,404,408,400,404,408,400,812,392,408,804,400,408,400,404,408,400,408,400,816,800,404,400,408,400,816,800,408,400,408,400,404,404,816,388,412,796,408,400,408,400,408,396,412,400,412,396,820,388,412,792,820,792,816,796,416,392,820,388,412,796,412,396,412,392,416,392,416,396,416,388,824,384,416,792,24636,400,380,400,372,400,380,396,380,396,380,396,384,396,380,400,376,396,384,396,380,396,380,396,380,396,384,392,384,392,384,392,388,392,384,388,388,392,384,392,388,392,388,388,384,396,3896,392,392,388,396,408,400,412,392,416,396,412,800,404,400,808,396,412,400,408,396,412,400,408,400,408,804,400,404,400,400,396,404,808,400,408,400,408,404,404,808,396,404,804,404,400,408,400,408,404,404,404,812,800,404,404,404,404,816,796,408,400,408,400,408,400,816,388,412,792,412,400,412,396,412,396,412,396,412,396,820,388,412,792,820,796,816,796,412,392,820,392,412,792,416,392,412,396,416,392,412,396,416,392,824,384,420,788,24632,404,376,400,376,400,376,400,380,400,376,400,380,396,380,392,384,396,380,396,384,392,384,396,380,396,380,392,388,392,384,392,388,388,388,388,388,392,384,392,384,392,384,392,388,392,3896,392,396,384,392,416,396,408,400,412,396,412,804,400,400,808,400,408,400,408,400,408,400,408,400,408,808,396,404,396,408,396,400,804,404,408,400,408,400,404,812,396,404,804,408,400,404,400,408,400,408,400,816,800,408,400,408,400,812,800,408,400,408,400,408,400,816,388,412,800,408,396,412,396,412,396,412,396,412,396,820,388,412,796,816,796,816,792,416,392,820,388,420,788,412,396,416,388,420,392,416,392,412,396,820,384,420,788

808,400,400,396,408,396,404,804,404,404,404,400,408,404,404,404,404,404,404,404,812,392,408,796,412,400,408,400,816,392,408,392,408,388,412,800,412,392,412,400,408,400,816,388,412,388,412,392,412,388,412,796,816,796,412,396,820,792,820,796,408,396,412,392,416,396,820,388,412,384,420,384,416,372,24248,404,376,396,380,400,376,400,376,400,380,396,380,396,380,396,380,400,380,392,388,392,380,396,384,392,384,392,384,396,380,392,384,392,388,392,384,392,388,388,388,388,388,388,388,396,3896,392,392,388,396,408,400,412,396,412,800,404,400,404,396,400,404,804,400,408,400,408,400,408,808,400,404,396,404,800,812,804,400,408,400,404,812,400,404,396,404,396,404,804,400,408,404,404,404,400,412,400,404,404,408,400,816,388,412,792,412,400,408,400,816,388,412,392,412,388,412,796,412,396,412,396,408,400,816,392,412,388,412,388,412,388,416,792,820,792,412,396,820,792,820,792,416,392,416,392,416,392,820,388,416,384,420,384,416,368,24248,404,376,400,380,396,380,400,376,400,376,400,380,392,384,396,380,400,380,392,384,396,384,392,380,392,384,396,384,392,384,392,388,388,388,388,388,392,388,388,384,392,388,388,388,396,3896,392,392,384,396,416,396,412,396,412,800,404,400,404,396,400,404,808,396,408,400,408,400,408,804,404,400,400,400,808,808,800,404,408,404,400,816,392,408,396,404,396,404,804,404,400,408,404,404,404,404,404,408,396,408,404,812,396,404,800,408,400,408,400,816,388,412,392,412,388,412,796,408,400,408,400,408,400,816,392,412,388,412,388,412,388,416,792,820,792,412,396,820,792,820,792,416,392,416,392,416,392,820,388,416,384,416,384,416,372,24248,404,376,404,372,404,376,400,376,396,380,400,376,400,380,396,380,396,380,396,380,396,384,396,380,396,384,388,388,392,384,392,384,392,384,392,388,388,384,392,392,388,388,384,388,392,3900,392,396,384,396,412,396,412,396,412,804,404,396,404,396,404,400,804,400,408,400,408,404,408,808,396,400,400,404,804,812,800,404,404,404,404,808,400,404,396,404,396,404,804,404,404,404,404,400,404,408,404,404,404,408,396,816,392,404,804,408,400,408,400,820,384,412,388
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: you may have decoded  the first two data streams incorrectly .... i  got these      `00000011000000111100001100000100010000110000001101010011000000110` ..... 
     `00000111100001110100011111111111001110000000011110101100100001111`

Comment: What happens if you just replay the recorded data? Does the curtain not respond if the 'counter' isn't updated?